# Jackrabbit AccessControll

Tags: jackrabbit

I have a issue that I can not find answer for here or in Jackrabbit documentation, hope that any of you can help with it.

I am doing the following:

- admin  create "someuser"
- admin create the above node:
  /templates/templateall[
      jcr:uuid: a9b629a4-d1dd-4ba3-a602-629e4ca1a7fd
      jcr:mixinTypes: mix:referenceable, rep:AccessControllable,
      label: templateall
      jcr:primaryType: nt:unstructured
      /templates/templateall/rep:policy[
              jcr:primaryType: rep:ACL
              /templates/templateall/rep:policy/allow[
                      rep:privileges: jcr:all,
                      rep:principalName: someuser
                      jcr:primaryType: rep:GrantACE
- someuser try to delete /templates/templateall node with the following exception on save()

javax.jcr.AccessDeniedException: /templates/templateall: not allowed to remove item
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemSaveOperation.validateTransientItems(ItemSaveOperation.java:704)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemSaveOperation.perform(ItemSaveOperation.java:216)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:216)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:91)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemImpl.save(ItemImpl.java:329)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionSaveOperation.perform(SessionSaveOperation.java:64)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:216)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:361)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:812)

- After, I try to delete /templates/templateall with admin user and the delete is completed successfully.
- Then I try to do the same but I give user "someuser" jcr:all access to node /templates instead of /templates/templateall, then "someuser" is able to delete the /templates/templateall successfully

So my conclusion with the first structure example is: "someuser" can remove any child of node /templates/templateall but not the node itself, is necesary to provide jcr:removeChildNodes acess no /templates to be able to do that.

Is my conclusion correct?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think yes. I don't know all the details about Jackrabbit security, but:

Removing a node in Jackrabbit modifies the parent node, because each node contains the list of child node ids.